# DataTable must be set prior to using DataView

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, sorting

When i try to sort my table manually, i receive this error:
DataTable must be set prior to using DataView.
The code is:

```
protected void GridView1_Sorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
    {

        DataTable sourceTable = GridView1.DataSource as DataTable;
        DataView view = new DataView(sourceTable);
        string[] sortData = Session["sortExpression"]!= null ? Session["sortExpression"].ToString().Trim().Split(' ') : null;
        if (sortData != null && e.SortExpression == sortData[0])
        {
            if (sortData[1] == "ASC")
            {
                view.Sort = e.SortExpression + " " + "DESC";
                Session["sortExpression"] = e.SortExpression + " " + "DESC";
            }
            else
            {
                view.Sort = e.SortExpression + " " + "ASC";
                Session["sortExpression"] = e.SortExpression + " " + "ASC";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            view.Sort = e.SortExpression + " " + "ASC";
            Session["sortExpression"] = e.SortExpression + " " + "ASC";
        }

    }
```

Where i wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely GridView1.DataSource is null.
You can find a tutorial on Gridview sorting here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.sorting.aspx

Answer (score 1):

It's possible your datatable also needs to be part of a dataset.

Similar to

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet()
DataTable sourceTable = GridView1.DataSource as DataTable;
ds.Tables.Add(sourceTable)
DataView view = new DataView(sourceTable);
string[] sortData = Session["sortExpression"]!= null ? Session["sortExpression"].ToString().Trim().Split(' ') : null;
```

This is only from weird past experience

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me when I MISTAKENLY tagged a class with the [DataObject] modifier.  That meant the entire class had to be 'bindable' as a DataSource, when in fact that was not the case.  Removing the tag removed the error.